# Возникновение события при изменении checkbox на JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Cкрипт, который делает видимыми или невидимыми контейнеры в зависимости от состояния соответствующего checkbox.
Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на чекбокс показывался только последний контейнер, а предыдущий скрывался. Т.е в не зависимости от кол-ва выбранных чекбоксов, активный контейнер был всегда один последний?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showOrHide(cb, cat) {
cb = document.getElementById(cb);
cat = document.getElementById(cat);
if (cb.checked) cat.style.display = "block";
else cat.style.display = "none";
}
</script>


<div><input type = 'checkbox' id = 'cb1' onchange = 'showOrHide("cb1", 
"cat1");'/>Показать содержимое категории 1
<br />
<div id = 'cat1' style = 'display: none;'>Содержимое категории 1</div>
<input type = 'checkbox' id = 'cb2' onchange = 'showOrHide("cb2", "cat2");' 
/>Показать содержимое категории 2
<br />
<div id = 'cat2' style = 'display: none;'>Содержимое категории 2</div>
<input type = 'checkbox' id = 'cb3' onchange = 'showOrHide("cb3", "cat3");' 
/>Показать содержимое категории 3
<br />
<div id = 'cat3' style = 'display: none;'>Содержимое категории 3</div></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно в самом начале функции `showOrHide` сделать невидимыми все контейнеры:

```js
function showOrHide(cb, cat) {
    
    document.getElementById('cat1').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('cat2').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('cat3').style.display = "none";
    
    cb = document.getElementById(cb);
    cat = document.getElementById(cat);
    if (cb.checked) cat.style.display = "block";
      else cat.style.display = "none";
    }
```

```html
<div><input type = 'checkbox' id = 'cb1' onchange = 'showOrHide("cb1", 
"cat1");'/>Показать содержимое категории 1
<br />
<div id = 'cat1' style = 'display: none;'>Содержимое категории 1</div>
<input type = 'checkbox' id = 'cb2' onchange = 'showOrHide("cb2", "cat2");' 
/>Показать содержимое категории 2
<br />
<div id = 'cat2' style = 'display: none;'>Содержимое категории 2</div>
<input type = 'checkbox' id = 'cb3' onchange = 'showOrHide("cb3", "cat3");' 
/>Показать содержимое категории 3
<br />
<div id = 'cat3' style = 'display: none;'>Содержимое категории 3</div></div>
```

Если же div-ов будет много, то можно добавить им type, далее с помощью `document.querySelectorAll` получить массив нужных div-ов, потом, проходя по этому массиву, ставить `style.display = "none"` (в сниппете `type = 'mytype'`).

```js
function showOrHide(cb, cat) {   
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div[type=mytype]');
  for(var i=0; i < divs.length; i++)
     divs[i].style.display = "none";
    
  cb = document.getElementById(cb);
  cat = document.getElementById(cat);
  if (cb.checked) cat.style.display = "block";
     else cat.style.display = "none";
  }
```

```html
<div><input type = 'checkbox' id = 'cb1' onchange = 'showOrHide("cb1", 
"cat1");'/>Показать содержимое категории 1
<br />
<div type = 'mytype' id = 'cat1' style = 'display: none;'>Содержимое категории 1</div>
<input type = 'checkbox' id = 'cb2' onchange = 'showOrHide("cb2", "cat2");' 
/>Показать содержимое категории 2
<br />
<div type = 'mytype' id = 'cat2' style = 'display: none;'>Содержимое категории 2</div>
<input type = 'checkbox' id = 'cb3' onchange = 'showOrHide("cb3", "cat3");' 
/>Показать содержимое категории 3
<br />
<div type = 'mytype' id = 'cat3' style = 'display: none;'>Содержимое категории 3</div></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное дружище!

Comment: Ок. Отмечай ответ как правильный, если это то, что было нужно.