# При клике на чекбокс отрывается несколько строк текста (скрытых блоков с текстом)

Tags: html, checkbox

Данный вопрос относится к уже созданной теме: [Возникновение события при изменении checkbox на JavaScript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/654243/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-checkbox-%D0%BD%D0%B0-javascript/712191?noredirect=1#comment1066184_712191)

Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на чекбокс открывалась не одна строка с текстом, а несколько, и у каждой был прописан класс. Или, может быть, поместить каждую строку в див, для того чтобы можно было строки прописать в любое место на странице. И при клике по чекбоксу они все открывались.

Или сделать что-то вроде этого, только чтобы был не один див с индификатором и классами внутри, а 6. При клике на чекбокс появлялись одни строки в нужных мне местах. При клике на другой чекбокс появлялись другие строки.

```
<script>
function change(obj) {
    var elems = document.getElementById('elems').getElementsByTagName('li');
    for(i=0;i<elems.length;i++) {
      if (elems[i].className == 'off') {
         if (obj.checked)
            elems[i].style.display = 'none';
         else
            elems[i].style.display = 'list-item';
      }
   }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чекбоксу задаешь класс `.checkbox-toggler` и аттрибут `data-target` со значением класса блока который тебе надо показывать/скрывать. Блоку(ам) соответственно нужному задать тот же класс, что в `data-target`

```js
const togglers = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox-toggler');

for(let checkbox of togglers) {
  checkbox.addEventListener('change', toggleOnChange);
}

function toggleOnChange() {
  const checkbox = this,
    checkboxTarget = checkbox.dataset.target,
    targets = document.getElementsByClassName(checkboxTarget);
    
  for(let target of targets) {
    if(checkbox.checked) {
      target.classList.remove('hidden');
    } else {
      target.classList.add('hidden');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.block-1,
.block-2 {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.block-1 { background-color: red; }
.block-2 { background-color: green; }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-toggler" data-target="block-1">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-toggler" data-target="block-2">
<div class="block-1 hidden">
  <input type="text">
</div>
<div class="block-2 hidden">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
</div>
<div class="block-2 hidden">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
</div>

<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-toggler" data-target="list-item_2">

<ul>
  <li>Пункт 1</li>
  <li class="list-item_2 hidden">Пункт 2</li>
  <li>Пункт 3</li>
  <li class="list-item_2 hidden">Пункт 4</li>
  <li class="list-item_2 hidden">Пункт 5</li>
</ul>

<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-toggler" data-target="lorem_1">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-toggler" data-target="lorem_2">

<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <span class="lorem_1 hidden">consectetur adipiscing elit, </span>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. <span class="lorem_2 hidden">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
</p>

<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-toggler" data-target="list-item_1-1">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-toggler" data-target="list-item_1-2">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-toggler" data-target="list-item_1-3">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-toggler" data-target="list-item_1-4">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-toggler" data-target="list-item_1-5">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-toggler" data-target="list-item_1-6">

<ul>
  <li class="list-item_1-1 hidden">Пункт 1</li>
  <li class="list-item_1-2 hidden">Пункт 2</li>
  <li class="list-item_1-3 hidden">Пункт 3</li>
  <li class="list-item_1-4 hidden">Пункт 4</li>
  <li class="list-item_1-5 hidden">Пункт 5</li>
  <li class="list-item_1-6 hidden">Пункт 6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Нет. Это не то. есть шаблон текста. При клике на чекбокс он добавляет нужные строчки в текст

Comment: @MedvedevDev - ну что же Вы так! Не угадали, что нужно Ирине :(.

Comment: Мне нужно что бы куски текста имели свой индификатор, а не див и в нем один кусок текста. Чтобы потом мне в шаблон поместить их в нужные мне места.

Comment: Добавил пару примеров как это работает с текстом, проверь, может все же оно? Я может чего-то не понимаю, но кажется эта штука работает с любыми элементами ...

Comment: Вот вопрос и был. У меня чекбоксов 6 (как в вашем примере с пунктами). И я не могу подцепить к каждому чекбоксу свои строчки.

Comment: Добавил пример того что вы описали, если это тоже не то, то я сдаюсь.

Comment: Вот я дошла тоже до этого момента. Только что бы у каждого чикбокса было не по одной строчке, а от двух и более. А так в нужную сторону мыслите.

Comment: Я вот не могу подцепить строчки (от 2х и более) к каждому инпуту. Я делала также дивами. Но думаю у строчек должен или у каждой свой класс. Или див  вместе с строчками прописать к импуту. И так к каждому импуту свой индификатор с строчками.

Comment: При чем нужно не забывать что строчки нужно прописать потом мне в определенные места на сранице. Скрипт, который я прислала. Дает мне прописать класс к строчкам в нужные места. Но он действует на все чекбоксы.

Comment: Этот метод работает с любыми элементами и без разницы сколько их на странице. Добавляете инпуту class="checkbox-toggler" и аттрибут data-target="{любой класс}", создаете хоть 100 строчек в разных концах страницы с классом который прописан в data-target ... Логика же простая ... есть чекбокс, отслеживается его выбор, когда он выбран ищутся все элементы на страницы которые имеют класс равный значению data-target этого чекбокса (элементы могут быть абсолютно любыми, хоть инпуты, хоть дивы,...). Без разницы где и сколько будет таких элементов, они все будут добавлять/убирать класс hidden

Comment: В общем уже просто из пустого в порожнее переливаем. Советую вам просто попробовать этот код, если будут с ним проблемы, опишите с чем они связаны. А так мы просто не понимаем друг друга и судя по кол-ву ответов никто тоже не понимает в чем проблема того что я вам предлагаю.

Comment: второй чекбокс в примере управляет 2умя дивами, с тем же успехом вместо этих дивов могли быть строки находящиеся в разных частях страницы. 3 чекбокс управляет 3мя элементами списка, с тем же успехом эти 3 элемента могли находиться в разных списках, в разных частях страницы и все равно бы все работало.

Comment: Все получилось. Огромное спасибо за помощь.